# Board connector for solder pads

Tags: connector, board

Beginner question: I have a sensor board which has 6 solder pads (in parallel to each other, just a line of 6 pads), but no holes. Do there exist any connectors (like molex) that allow to fit the connector to the board? I didn't find any suitable connectors, but maybe I am using the wrong search terms. It seems all connectors require holes in the board.

Or do I simply have to solder the (flat) wire directly onto the board solder pads?

**EDIT**
Here is a picture of the pads. The distance between the center of the first and last pad is 7.5 mm (I made a measurement error before). The solder pads are in the middle of the board, not near the edge.

[image]

Comment: A picture showing "geometry" sold be useful.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for _card edge_ connectors, although those typically require pads on both sides of the PCB and are also somewhat picky with PCB thickness (1.6mm is by far most common). Please post a picture.

Comment: What's the size and pitch of the pads? If they're large and spaced far apart, finding a connector will probably be easy; if they're small and close together, finding a connector will probably be hard.

Comment: That's 1.5mm pitch, pretty fine. If there is a connector that it has been designed to fit there will be additional outboard pads and/or holes to provide support.

Comment: Please show us a wider view of the area with more of the surrounding board visible. There may be other features surrounding those pads which would help to identify a more specific connector.

Comment: @DavideAndrea There are 5 spaces between the 6 pads, 7.5/5 = 1.5.

Comment: You are correct. I apologise for my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JST ZH](https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/zh-connector/)

P/N [B6B-ZR-SM4-TF(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/B6B-ZR-SM4-TF-LF-SN/926592)

6 circuits, 1.5 mm pitch, surface mount, straight

Mating plug: P/N [ZHR-6](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/ZHR-6/527361)

Place it so that the PCB terminals are centered on the pads. You won't be able to solder the mounting terminals at either end.

Do understand that SMD pads are delicate: if you pull on the wires to the plug, the pads may lift off the PCB

Comment: OP has indicated that the pads have a 1.5mm pitch, not 2.5mm.

Comment: 6 pads in one line = 5 times the pitch = 7.5/5 = 1.5mm

Comment: I am embarrassed. Thank you for catching my first-thing-in-the-morning mistake.